# UI libraries for developing Chrome Applications

Tags: gridview, google-chrome-app

Are there third party UI widget libraries available for developing Chrome Applications easily?

I want to avoid:

- Libraries that require sandboxing like Webix and Dhtmlx; and
- Libraries based on modules/require/CommonJS/Node.js that need browserifying.

Comment: Why do you need one?

Comment: I'm particularly interested in a good data grid control, rather than having to code a data grid myself.

Comment: I have just now found AlloyUI which looks like it may be an answer.  I'll add it as an answer later if it passes my testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just a good grid control, gridedit.js is easily to implement in Chrome Apps:

- http://www.cssscript.com/easy-editable-data-grid-with-vanilla-javascript-gridedit/
- https://github.com/gridedit/gridedit

Answer (score 2):

Alloy UI (http://alloyui.com/) is built on YUI which can work in Chrome App.

YUI will by default download any components that are not included, but this causes security errors in Chrome, so it must be prevented by downloading and including the full library in the Chrome crx.

The library also uses Function if not supplied with a configuration via globals.

Using this answer: [How do I use YUI3 in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967130/how-do-i-use-yui3-in-a-chrome-extension) , I built the following config.js file to set the globals before I load aui.js:

```
var theGlobalObject = this;

YUI_config = {
    filter: "raw",
    base: "../lib/alloyui/",
    root: "../lib/alloyui/",
    comboBase: "/combo?",
    combine: false,
    groups: {
        gallery: {
            base: "../lib/alloyui/",
            root: "../lib/alloyui/",
            comboBase: "/combo?",
            combine: false,
            patterns: {
                "gallery-": {},
                "gallerycss-": { type: "css" }
            }
        }
    },
    global: theGlobalObject
};
```

With ../lib/alloyui/ being the path of the AlloyUI libraries relative to my html in my Chrome App folders.